# python async library for Neo4j

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous, neo4j, tornado, py2neo

I am using p2neo for querying neo4j DB, some quires are taking more than a second to respond, is there any async library I can use with tornado framework to communicate with neo4j.

Comment: Just checking ... when running the same queries in the browser they respond with subsecond performance ? If not you might want us to take a look at the queries first ...

Comment: @TomGeudens I checked on the browser also, the query takes more or less same amount of time

Comment: Fair enough. So it's not p2neo that is the issue really and we should take a look at the queries, agreed ? Sure, you can bombard the server with simultaneous queries but that will only go as far as you can throw cores at the problem (each query is single-threaded, async does not solve that).

Comment: it might be overkill to use aiohttp with Tornado, but take a look at aioneo4j (https://github.com/wikibusiness/aioneo4j) (no support to bolt)